# Implement Sinch dialpad when the call is established

Tags: android, sinch

I am currently developing an application of the App to Phone type. I would like to know how to use the DialPad when the call is in progress. Which method should I use, or invocation. Unfortunately I have looked for examples that explain how to do it but I could not find any.

They could be so kind to explain to me how to do what I need.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send DTMF there is a method for sendDTMF on the call object. Sinch dont provide a dial pad ui, so how to invoce that is up to you. Either make sure a numberic  keyboard is open when the call is answered or create your own custom dialpad

Comment: what about receiving DTMF, not sending?